# Why does ltrim remove one character too much?

Tags: php, trim

```
<?php
echo ltrim('12Hello World', '\x30..\x39');
echo "<br />";
echo ltrim('12Hello World', '0123456789');
```

Gives the output:

```
ello World
Hello World
```

Why? I understand that it is an array of characters and every character is stripped but if that's the case why is the `H` removed in the first case?

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us all your code? Please show any code at the beginning.

Comment: @nl-x it's reproduceable. On 5.5 At least.

Comment: It strips \, x, 3, range 0 to \, 3, 9. \ is between lowercase letters and uppercase letters in ASCII table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`'\x30..\x39'` is the following character mask:

- `\`
- `x`
- `3`
- `0..\`, i.e. anything from `0` through `\`, which includes `H`
- `9`

You need to use *double quotes*, otherwise the `\xXX` escape sequences aren't interpreted as bytes:

```
"\x30..\x39"
```

That's the character mask for anything from byte `x30` through `x39`, which is 0 - 9 in ASCII and compatible encodings.

Answer (score 3):

Escape sequences aren't interpreted inside single quotes. So your second argument is interpreted literally. It says to trim the following characters:

- `\`
- `x`
- `3`
- `0` through `\`
- `x`
- `3`
- `9`

If you take a look at an [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/), you'll see that the range `0` through `\` includes all the uppercase letters.

Change to a double-quoted string to have the hex escape sequence interpreted:

```
echo ltrim("12Hello World", "\x30..\x39")
```

produces:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **double quote** when you mean to use hexadecimal ascii character.

```
// range 0 to 9
echo ltrim('12Hello World', "\x30..\x39"); // output will be Hello World
```

If you use single quote, then the character_mask `'\x30..\x39'` will be explained as

the characters `'\'`, `'x'`, `'3'`, range from char `'0'` to `'\'`, and `'x'`, `'3'`, `'9'`.